# Keras get_weights() doesn't show full output

Tags: neural-network, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I'm currently using Keras to solve a regression problem. 
And I want the weights of my layers (embedding layers).

I'm using `layer.get_weights()` from keras, but it doesn't show me the full output.

Already tried to `save_weights()` but when I try to convert the hdf5 file it says that is empty.

Any solution?

Comment: You should post your code, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean it does not show the full output?